# Notification fired only one time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-alarms

I'm trying to make an app that fires notifications every time the user has to take a medicine.

ISSUE: I want to send a notification **at a specific time**. I searched on the Internet but I only found tutorials that explain how to send notifications after a specified interval of time. I have more times stored in an SQLite database and I want to fire a notification for every of them, like an alarm clock.

This is my `setAlarm()` function (If something is not clear, please ask):

```
public void setAlarm()
{
    String mName = NameFld.getText().toString();
    String mFormat = FormatSpn.getSelectedItem().toString();

    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();

    current.setTime(date);
    calendar.setTime(date);

    char[] sTime = TimeBtn.getText().toString().toCharArray();

    if(sTime[0] == '0')
    {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sTime[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        String tmp = "";
        tmp += sTime[0];
        tmp += sTime[1];

        int hour = Integer.parseInt(tmp);

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    }

    if(sTime[3] == '0')
    {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, sTime[4]);
    }
    else
    {
        String tmp = "";
        tmp += sTime[3];
        tmp += sTime[4];

        int minute = Integer.parseInt(tmp);

        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    }

    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


    if(current.before(calendar))
    {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

    medName = mName;
    medFormat = mFormat;

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager aManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    aManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);

}
```

This function splits the date in hour and minute values and sets them to the `Calendar`. Once running I get notifications with no title and text (I manage them in a `static` function that sends medicine data to the `BroadcastReceiver` class) and when I add a new alarm, it doesn't fire. Like I said before, I'd like to get notifications **for each time value**.

This is the `BroadcastReceiver` class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String[] data = AddMedicine.getData();

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setTicker("It's pill time!");
    builder.setContentTitle(data[0]);
    builder.setContentText(data[1]);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nManager.notify(AddMedicine.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    AddMedicine.NOTIFICATION_ID++;
}
}
```

If anyone could solve my problem, I will really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is the `getData()` method, that provides name and format of the medicine in order to put them in the building of the notification:

```
public static String[] getData()
{
    String[] data = {medName, medFormat};
    return data;
}
```

`medName` and `medFormat` are global variables initialized inside the `setAlarm()` method.

Comment: can you explain this line : String[] data = AddMedicine.getData(); ,  from where are getting the data , what's the AddMedicine class , why you're not using intent extras to send data to the AlarmReceiver ?

Comment: `getData()` is a method within the AddMedicine class, the same class where the `setAlarm()` method is. I don't use intent extras because I can't call the `getIntent()` method inside a class that extends `BroadcastReceiver`, which has no `onCreate()` method. 
I'll edit the question adding the `getData()` method.

Comment: you can get `Intent` extras from the intent in the onReceive method parameters which corresponds to "The Intent being received." as mentioned in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

- You are using same REQUEST_CODE for your PendingIntent, which replacing other PendingIntent's.
- Use different request codes (2nd parameter) for your **PendingIntent.getBroadcast()** method for every call.
- You can use **SharedPref** to store one counter which will increment for each PendingIntent.
  Example :-

  ```
  int reminderRequestCode = sPrefs.getInt(KeyConstants.PREF_REMINDER_REQUEST_CODE, -1);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 
  *reminderRequestCode*, myIntent,0);
  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
  alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPrefs.edit();
  editor.putInt(KeyConstants.PREF_REMINDER_REQUEST_CODE, ++reminderRequestCode);
  editor.commit();
  ```

Comment: I still don't get any notification, sorry!

Comment: Make sure your AlarmReceiver is properly declared in android manifest.

Answer (score 0):

> when I add a new alarm, it doesn't fire

You have to use a unique identifier (`requestCode` field of `getBroadcast`method) for each `PendingIntent` because you're using the same one ( 0 ) for all of the instances with the `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` so only the last created one will be fired.

> I get notifications with no title and text

I think you have to use `Intent`extras to send datas to the `AlarmReceiver` because in your case data are changin before `AlarmReceiver` gets fired so you get wrong values.

Comment: I'll manage the Extras issue in a second time, for the moment I changed the code as follows: http://gyazo.com/065d27b98d576f45e12d2235adc687dd
But I still don't get notifications. Have I to change something inside the `AlarmReceiver` class too?

Comment: Is  the `AlarmReceiver` gets fired ? , make a `Log` to test it gets fired correctly for each `PendigIntent`

Comment: sorry, I'm pretty sure that the problem isn't in setting alarm or in the `AlarmReceiver` but I think you have a problem in datas ( alarmTime ... ) ,  please try to test the alarm separately with static datas